# Recursion if Condition

Tags: c, if-statement, conditional-statements, dynamic-programming

The following is an implementation of the problem from spoj:- http://www.spoj.com/problems/COINS/

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ll long long

ll arr[100000];

ll max(ll n)
{
    if(n < 49999)// Doubt
    {
        if(!arr[n])
            return arr[n] = max(n/2) + max(n/3) + max(n/4);
        else
            return arr[n];
    }
    else
        return max(n/2) + max(n/4) + max(n/3);
}


int main()
{
    ll n, c = 0, i;

    for(i = 0; i < 12; i++) // Also why 12 when the input can be <12
    {
        arr[i] = i;
    }

    while(scanf("%lld", &n) != EOF)
    {
        printf("%lld\n", max(n));

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Why does the if condition contain n<49999?

Comment: @SouravGhosh Why 49999 specifically?

Comment: I'd suggest that you take 50000 and work out manually what will happen in your array.

Comment: It seems there is no theoretical reason for it being 49999. It could as well be 99999.

Comment: I think that the person that made the program, made use of a debugger like `gdb` extensively and then hardcoded those magic values or limits (however you want to call it) :\

Comment: why obscure the code with the `#define ll long long` statement?  code should be written as clear as possible.  instances of `ll` in the code is not writing clear code

Comment: regarding this line: `while(scanf("%lld", &n) != EOF)` the correct value to check for is 1,  any other value, including EOF, is an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

without having examined each possibility, other than the first 20+ values and the max and min values:

MY expectation is

the first 12 entries in the arr[] are pre-calculated to help reduce the depth of a recursion however the dollar value is not the same as the calculated value for those first 12 entries.

for coin values <= 49999, check to see if value already calculated, if not then break the coin into the /2 /3 /4 values and recurse each of those resulting values.

This limit value (49999) could be extended to 100000 as that is the available size of the arr[] array.

the presetting and the saving into the arr[] array are to help reduce execution time taken and the depth of the recursion.

the use of the array is so any previously calculated values (in the posted code, up to 49999) can be immediately returned by the `max()` function, without further recursion.

I would modify the code slightly for better documentation and robustness and faster execution as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define MAX_ARRAY_LEN (100000)

uint32_t arr[ MAX_ARRAY_LEN ] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11};

uint32_t max(uint32_t n)
{
    if(n < MAX_ARRAY_LEN)
    { // value of 'n' within the range of the learning array arr[]

        if(!arr[n] && n)
        { // then learning array arr[] not yet set
            return arr[n] = max(n/2) + max(n/3) + max(n/4);
        }

        else
        { // else learning array arr[] already set for 'this' value of 'n'
            return arr[n];
        }
    }

    else
    { // value of 'n' is greater than the learning array arr[]
        return max(n/2) + max(n/4) + max(n/3);
    }
} // end function: max


int main( void )
{
    uint32_t n;

    int status;
    while( (status = scanf("%u", &n)) == 1 && EOF != status)
    {
        if( 1000000000 >= n)
        {
            printf("%u\n", max(n) );
        }

        else
        {
            printf(" invalid value entered, must be in the range 0...1 000 000 000\n");
        } // end if
    } // end while

    return 0;
} // end function: main
```

Comment: Why do you think that someone with a coin worth 3 would only get $2 out of this when they can exchange it at the 1:1 conversion rate for $3?  For each coin worth less than 12, they get the maximum exchange by simply converting it directly, as implemented in the code in the question.  For a coin worth 12, they can get ⎣12/2⎦ + ⎣12/3⎦ + ⎣12/4⎦ = 13, as you correctly show.

Comment: I made the modificiations to this new answer, and per the SPOJ it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

As far I understand that,

> The person who write the code, somehow he found out that (manually) if
>   the coin less than 12 then result will be itself. so that he use 12.
>   (check the explanation of the input coin = 2)

And about the recursion function

> as we know we can't declare array with 1,000,000,000 size so he try to
>   use some other value (49999 here) in which size he can create array
>   and later take the result for the coin in array like arr[12] = 13
>   (where 12 is coin and 13 is the result) so that he can get the result
>   without generate for the value by using that array with arr[12] (only)
>   for coin 12.

Hope you understand.

Comment: What's curious is that the array size in the question is 100,000 but the test in the code limits its use to the first 49,999 of the 100,000 elements.  That is probably an accident of editing — caused in part by not using an `enum` or `#define` value for the array size, or not using `sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0])` as the number of elements in the array.  There's also an element of 'off-by-one': if the size of the array was 50,000, the limit should be `< 50000` and not `< 49999`.